# How to set and clear bits without ~ operator

Tags: c, math, embedded

I am using a C like script for Bluegiga chip and their scripting langauge does not have the `~` operator in the compiler. 
Is there any way to work with bits using pure math?
For example i read a byte and i need to clear bit 1 and set bit 2.

```
The following bitwise operations are supported:
Operation              Symbol
 AND                     &
 OR                      |
 XOR                     ^
 Shift left              <<
 Shift right             >>

The following mathematical operators are supported:
Operation              Symbol
 Addition:               +
 Subtraction:            -
 Multiplication:         *
 Division:               /
 Less than:              <
 Less than or equal:     <=
 Greater than:           >
 Greater than or equal:  >=
 Equals:                 =
 Not equals:             !=
```

Comment: In 2's complement: `-x = ~x + 1` => `~x = -x - 1 = -(x + 1)` ; the XOR answer is obviously more efficient though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use OR and AND operations. To do that operation:

initial byte: 0000 0001

clear bit 1: 0000 0001 & 1111 1110 --> result - 0000 0000 (The 1st bit of the second operand must be 0 to clear the bit)

now set bit 2: 0000 0000 | 0000 0010 --> result - 0000 0010 (The 2st bit of the second operand must be 1 to set the bit)

Note that for this operations you only change the specific bit all the other remain with the same value.

Also to obtain the second operand you can just obtain it by:
for the set operation on the n bit - the second operand is 2^n

for the clear operation on the n bit - the second operand is 1111 1111 XOR 2^n (in this case 1111 1111 XOR is used for the not operation).

Comment: unfortunately it will affect the other bits in the byte.

Comment: yes in this edition the clearing 1 bit won't affect the other bits.

Answer (score 1):

If you are missing the `~` operator, you can make your own using XOR and a constant.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    unsigned int s = 0xFFFFFFFF ;

    printf("%#x" , 0xFF ^ s ) ;  //XOR with the constant is equivalent to ~


    unsigned int byte = 0x4 ;
    printf("%#x" , 0x5 & ( byte ^ s ) ) ; //clear those bits

return 0 ;
}
```

When you have `~` it is easy to clear the bits.

Answer (score 1):

Clearing a (single) bit is also equivalent to SET following by INVERT (or xor). Thus.

```
 aabbccdd  <-- original value
 00000110   OR                
 00000010  XOR
 --------
 aabbc10d  <-- result (I'm counting the bits from 7 downto 0)
```

This approach has the benefit of being scalable from byte to the native integer size without the burden of calculating the mask for AND operation.

Answer (score 0):

Performing a XOR against -1 will invert all the bits in an integer.